# Function in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, function, parameters, flash-cs5.5

i try to make a function like this:

```
    function splashlafadz(obj:MovieClip):void{
var varsplash1 = new TimelineMax({delay:3});
varsplash1.to(obj, 1, {alpha:100, x:427.85, y:208.90, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});
varsplash1.to(obj, 1,{visible:false, delay:3});
}
```

then, i have a movieclip named splash1..how can i apply that function to splash1?
i try to use

```
splashlafadz.call(splash1);
```

but it getting error..
how can i use the function to be used with a different movieclip?

Can I make a sound a parameter??so each of movieclip have a different sound?

Comment: splashlafadz(splash1);

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another parameter to pass the sound you'd like to use :

```
function splashlafadz(obj:MovieClip, sound:Sound):void{
    var varsplash1 = new TimelineMax({delay:3});
    varsplash1.to(obj, 1, {alpha:100, x:427.85, y:208.90, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:1});
    varsplash1.to(obj, 1,{visible:false, delay:3});
    sound.play();
}
```

Then you just call it like so :

```
splashlafadz(yourObject, yourSound);
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a function you can just use the function name directly, like this: `splashlafadz(splash1)`.

The `call` function is required when you want to change the `this` object, it's quite likely you won't ever need it. There's some thorough documentation on MDN right here: [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). (This reference is for JavaScript, but it works the same way as Action Script).

Comment: and what about a sound?can i make a sound a parameter? can i insert to that function? @andypaxo